# Why can I save a .sh file as .txt and it still works when I run it

Tags: sh

I have this in my myshellscript.txt:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -f $1 ]
then
 cat $1
else
 echo "Sorry, not found"
fi
```

Why is that even though it is a .txt file I can still run it using sh myshellscript.txt someotherfile.txt

Comment: because unix doesn't care about file extensions. you could rename your shell script `cutekittens.jpg` and it would still work. As long as it's got the execute bit (`chmod +x`) and starts with a `#!...` shebang, it'll be a program, regardless of what the filename is. And when you pass it directly into `sh` as you are, as a command line argument, you don't even need the execute bit at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you put a shebang (magic line) in the first line:

```
#!/bin/sh
```

This makes your shell know, it is a script it can run. At least if you made the file executable (`chmod +x myshellscript.txt`). UNIX does not care about file extensions as much as Windows does, so it does not depend on the file extension, whether a script is executable or not.

Comment: When it is run using `sh myshellscript.txt someotherfile.txt`, it doesn't matter whether it starts with a shebang or not — or whether the shebang says `#!/bin/sh` or `#!/usr/bin/kleptomaniac` or anything else.  The shebang matters when the script file is executable and is run using `myshellscript.txt someotherfile.txt`.

Comment: That is why you would set the execute bit in the first place.

Comment: In the absence of the `#!` line, a script is executed with `/bin/sh` by default.(Omitting the `#!` is *not* a good idea.)

Comment: The question explicitly asks about why it works when run using `sh myshellscript.txt some otherwise.txt`, which doesn't even require the file to be executable to work.  You're right if the script is run without the shell being specified on the command line, but strictly that isn't what the question is asking about; it is the next question.